# Does Jiren simply use brute force?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Hit is a powerful opponent for Goku because he can use time skip and manipulate time and space.
Could this be said for Jiren, or is he simply an overpowered character?
I'm **NOT** comparing the two, I'm simply providing an example.

Comment: From what I've seen Jiren is just crazy strong. Most of the villains in the DBZ universe kind of of follow a niche (Freeza had multiple forms, Cell had all the cells of the world's strongest, Buu was a demon of unimaginable power). Jiren is just broken it doesn't seem like he uses any sort of real powers or abilities yet. As the tournament progresses, I'm sure something will come out

Comment: He hasnt showed any special abilities other than predicting object and person movements

Answer (score 2):

**Jiren is not overpowered.**

*tl;dr More Power (KI) ≠ Stronger Fighter*

---

The point of the character is to illustrate the difference of strength between powerful mortals, gods of destruction, angels and others we probably haven't seen yet. *Jiren could be at a level between god of destruction and angel*. The fact that he seems overpowered means we still have a long way to go until Goku reaches a level where he is considered the strongest.

In *DBZ* and even *GT*, Goku seems to be near to the level of all of his opponents before finally surpassing them. *Super* is taking a different approach. Goku and the others are struggling to even perceive the strength of their opponents. Other techniques and skills throw a monkey wrench in the idea of "more power = stronger fighter". Time skip, ultra instinct, and the energy of destruction are all examples of technique trumping raw power.

The new anime is changing power scaling and what it means to be a powerful fighter. *DBZ* and *GT* relied on transformations to show a character was at a higher level. *Super*, like the original *Dragon Ball*, is pivoting to strategy and use of different techniques to show a fighter's skills are advancing.

Answer (score 0):

Jiren is just overpowered that's all. But Goku (or even Vegeta) with ultra instinct can maybe win against him somehow... Its hard to believe that this beast can be beaten but yes... it is possible.

Comment: Just pure speculation here, but maybe he won't be beaten. It is also possible that Goku's universe simply wins due to remaining number of people still in the ring. So technically Jiren won't be defeated in terms of fighting. But for the tournament itself his universe will most likely lose. Goku might be able to take him head one until time runs out. By default the universe with the most people still standing in the ring will then win. In the arc with Zamasu we were shown that in dbs... some villians remain undefeated, unless it is for Zen-oh.

Answer (score 0):

Let me make something clear, Hit isn't a character strong for his power(If compared to the power of these high tiers and godly tier characters). What makes him strong are his dangerous assassin techniques which allow him to manipulate time and space

- Even during the first fight between Goku and Hit during the Universe 6 vs Universe 7 arc, we need to realize that both of Goku's very powerful attacks didn't actually touch Hit. Hit's timeskip allowed him to dodge both the attacks which is why he managed to survive.
- Even during the rematch between Goku and Hit, we see Goku capable of tanking multiple blows from Hit and even surviving a shot which almost killed him. However, one powerful Kamehameha in his improvised SSJB form, was capable of taking out Hit (a double K.O), during the match.

  Even during the match between Hit and Dyspo, we see Dyspo's punches actually hurting hit a lot at the start. We see Goku on the other hand taking 2 back to back punches from Dyspo like it was nothing.

If I were to distinguish the current strongest characters(mortals), I'd put them on the God Tier and the High Tier Scale :

## God Tier

1. Jiren: He is the strongest mortal in the anime at the moment and his power is said to rival that of a Hakaishin. He obviously possesses a lot of techniques and experience like Goku but ultimately, what makes him unbelievable strong is just his brute strength and power. We do know that technique can sometimes counter power. (We see hit being able to do this with goku), However,  Jiren's power rivals that of Beerus (at 100%). So his power is off the scale and even Hit's best technique wasn't sufficient enough to subdue him.
2. UI Goku: This transformation is Goku utilising a skill which the Gods strive to master. At the same time, it certainly does act as a power multiplier which makes him very strong and he's definitely not in his base form or his attacks wouldn't even touch Kefla or Jiren. One's he manages to attack perfectly in this state, and match Jiren's power, it would bring him closer to the power of the gods

## High Tier

1. Goku SSJB + Kaioken*20
2. Kefla SSJ2
3. Toppo
4. Vegeta SSJB = Golden Freiza
5. Hit

In terms of power, Hit is a lot weaker than the rest of the high tier characters. He is certainly very powerful, but even a mid tier character like 17, gohan or dyspo (Fighting at full power) might be able to give Hit some trouble if they manage to counter his special abilities which they very likely wouldn't be able to because of Hit's superior experience and complex level of skill. Also, you need to realize that Goku wouldn't struggle with Hit's time skip anymore in his UI state. Unlike Goku who needed some time to adjust to time skip, Jiren was able to completely dodge all of Hits attacks and even counter most of the time initially simply because of his amazing reaction time. The UI transformation makes Goku's reaction time perfect, so technically, Goku would be able to dodge hit's time skip and overpower him.

Answer (score -1):

**Overpowered** is the correct description for Jiren. So far what was shown was pure raw power from Jiren. We weren't introduced to any special ability yet (in the anime, I don't know how it is in the manga).

It was rumored that a mortal was living in an universe with power that exceeds the god of destruction. I don't know the exact episode but Whis and Beerus were talking about it when Jiren showed his raw power for the first time.

If Jiren has any special/unique abilities it will still have to be presented. Which will make him significantly stronger or weaker if an ability might be the reason for his insane raw power.

Just the way saiyans and different species are able to power up through different forms Jiren might be possessing a similar treat.

Based on what we have been shown yet Jiren is simple overpowered. The punch of his fist alone causes enough force to destroy surrounding areas. None of the other characters in the tournament so far are able to have a similar force in their base form.

Comment: To be fair, not all characters require transformations to get stronger. That's an exclusive Saiyan trait. Fighters such as Jiren, Toppo, even the gods like Beerus, Champa(at least, since we've seen them fight), don't use any transformations. So there's no actual reason for Jiren having one. I'd say it's more of him suppressing his energy and utilizing the sufficient amount to overpower his opponent. Just like Beerus did when he fought, SSJ3 Goku and the Z fighters.

Comment: Thats true, but that means that they have a fixed raw power, the can lower their output, but the limit remains the same. A different form (for example) can increase this limit. Thats why I called it a "similar treat" since not all methods of powering up goes through transformations. But it is too early to conclude what Jiren's abilities/limits are in terms of powering up and such.